# Get control properties from Grid.Resources in code behind

Tags: wpf, resources, datatemplate

At the begining, theres xaml code:

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemp" x:Key="dtKey">
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="mainWP">
                    <TextBlock Name="codeTB" FontSize="18" Width="200" Text="{Binding barcode}"></TextBlock>
(...)
               </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

and listview with datatemplate:

```
<ListView Name="testLV" Grid.Row="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=dtKey}" >

        </ListView>
```

So in code behind i'd like to change TextBlock width as this.width/5 (becouse width could be different in another PC), but becouse it's DataTemplate i don't have access to this control.
I also tried Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=grid0}", but as actual width i need something like ActualWidth/5, which doesnt work

Thanks

Comment: Well Assuming you use this `DataTemplate` in the `Grid`, why don't you just setup your `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` accordingly to have width as say "0.2*" for the Column using this `DataTemplate` and then remove fixed width specifications from your `Datatemplate` all-together. Use of `TryFindResource(...)` is just going to make your code shabby and give you more problems later on. You could also use a converter to do the "ActualWidth/5" but pls don't. use WPF the right way(limit "magic number" fixed size specification) and you'll have a much better experience building your app.

Comment: Hmm, but im using DataTemplate for listview, ill edit first post and show that

Comment: Not sure if I understand that you're saying right :)
In DataTemplate i have wrappanel with 5 TextBlocks. So now i need to put Listview into Column - ok. But how about all controls which are in WrapPanel? I just want to split whole width into 5 controls (TextBlocks), which are inside Wrappanel.

Comment: In this case, when ill use Grid.ColumnDefinition ill just put ListView into 0.2* of Grid Width. But I want to have 0.2* foreach control declared in DataTemplate. So I need to have 100% width for ListView, and foreach control from DataTemplate something like ColumnDefinition to define their width

Comment: Now i get it. As DataTemplate i should use Grid with columnn definition instead of Wrappanel, right? ;) Ok, everything seems to work now, but that 0.2* width is calculated as 20% ow width? Becouse doesnt seems to look like :P

Comment: Ok. One more question - is there any difference between grid.resources, and binding ItemTemplate/DataTemplate for listview? As shown in code here: http://pastebin.com/kuWhZuth ?

Comment: And yea, well, it seems like doesnt really get that "0.2*" width ;/ http://i40.tinypic.com/2hye7a1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Grid` with 5 columns and each with `Width="0.2*"` will work fine when all the child element's `DesiredWidth` have been satisfied(In other words when the size of the Grid is large enough to fit all columns with equal space). If it cannot do this, The layout works in a way to trim elements it can and give the extra space to other columns that need it more thereby overriding the `Width="0.2*"` in the process

For your requirement where you want the 5 columns to be split equally, just use a `UniformGrid`. That pretty much doesn't care abt any of the above things.

So say something like:

```
<ListView Name="paragonLV" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="0" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
              Value="0" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <UniformGrid MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}},
                                      Path=ActualWidth}"
                    Columns="5">
        <UniformGrid.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
                    Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
          </Style>
        </UniformGrid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding barCode}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding nazwa}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding jm}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ilosc}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding cena}" />
      </UniformGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid.Columndefination to format your grid or otherwise use Ivaluconverter class let's see value converter development

convert parameter will your calculating parameter,
you know how to construct value converter class

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //value is grid actual width 
       // parameter = 5 is your calculated value

           return value / parameter;
    }
```